# Numerical solution of deterministic ODE + small stochastic (diffusion) part

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, numerical-methods

I am struggling with the following problem:
I have a system of first-order ODEs describing a motion of particle in a give potential (actually it's 3d but doesn't matter):

```
dx = v dt,
dv = f(x) dt,
```

plus a small stochastic component, which perturbs the velocity of the particle according to

```
dv = g(x,v) dt + h(x,v) dW,
```

where dW is the Wiener process. That is, my drift and diffusion coefficients depend on the position and velocity, but they are always small compared to the derivatives in the deterministic part of ODE.
I have many different methods for solving these equations (fixed-timestep 4th order RK, variable-timestep 8th order RK, Bulirsch-Stoer, etc.), which are excellent for the deterministic part. Then I thought that I could add the small perturbation to the velocity after each timestep of deterministic ODE integrator, by computing g and h at the end of timestep and slightly modifying the velocity as

```
dv += g dt + sqrt(h dt) * xi,
```

where xi is a random variable drawn from the standard normal distribution.

This works almost fine, but there is some bias in the long-term behaviour of particle energies (I compare it with the grid-based solution of Fokker-Planck equation describing the same process deterministically using the distribution function). What's worse, this bias is different (even changes sign) for different choices of ODE integrator, and doesn't go away when I decrease the timestep (actually becomes worse).

Reading various literature (e.g. Kloeden&Platen's book, or Higham(2001) introductory paper), it seems that things are much more subtle than I imagined, and I'm not even sure whether this task can be done in the way I attempt (that is, interleave the deterministic and stochastic part as in a symplectic integration kick-drift scheme). Any suggestions?

Comment: There are separate numerical methods for SDE. Their performance is unfortunately much worse than the corresponding methods for ODE. The simplest SDE method is Euler-Maruyama; the next one is Milstein, which is a bit more accurate. Higher order SDE methods than Milstein are not very popular because they are hard to implement (from the perspective of both what you have to know about your model and actual programming) and rather slow.

Comment: Yes, I reckoned the scarcity of efficient high-order methods for stochastic ODEs, that's why I wanted to retain a good solver for the main deterministic component (for the sake of argument, I may even consider it to be exact), and add an appropriate [small!] random perturbation. Is it possible at all in this formulation?

Comment: Typically no, not without introducing some slowly growing bias as you have observed. In particular, these higher order deterministic methods assume  regularity that you just don't have in SDEs. (For instance, the solution to an SDE like yours is $C^1$ but it has no more derivatives than that.) I'm not sure whether the fact that the white noise is exclusively affecting the velocity changes matters, though.

Comment: You may use the moment equation method to solve SDE (i.e find ODE that describe dynamics of moments).

Comment: @PawelKowal That depends on what exactly you want to achieve...

Comment: @Ian For example "Moment equation methods for nonlinear stochastic systems", D.C.C. Bover, ‎1978

Comment: I mean that you can only extract so much information from pointwise moments. Pathwise information is destroyed.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned, I may use an equivalent Fokker-Planck formulation to check the results of Monte Carlo integration for an ensemble of trajectories. But that's only possible for some special cases, and in general there is no such formulation.

Comment: I don't care that much about pointwise correctness of trajectories, but rather about their ensemble properties (that is, I should be happy with weak convergence). My hope is that if I pretend to know exactly the unperturbed trajectory (the deterministic ODE solver can be arbitrarily accurate), not only at the endpoints but for the entire timestep (i.e. an interpolation is available), I could use this information to integrate the stochastic differential h(x(t),v(t)) dW, where x,v(t) are taken along the unperturbed trajectory. I can afford to evaluate h(x,v) multiple times during the timestep.

Comment: Your "hope" is not how things actually work, unfortunately. Building your hope into the scheme would require you to adapt your step size so that the perturbed trajectory actually *is* close to the unperturbed trajectory over the time interval over which you take the approximate integrations.

Comment: Whether that happens depends on what the noise is doing, and with white noise as the driving force, it *cannot* be entirely removed with just small noise intensity or a small uniform step size. It can in principle be removed by using *adaptive* step sizes, but this now requires you to augment the method to avoid the adaptive method causing intrinsic biases in the solution.